# Spring cloud stream Kinesis producer can't connect to localstack

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, localstack, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream-binder, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

Using spring boot and spring cloud stream, I am trying to send messages to Kinesis on localstack Kinesis instance run on docker but it gives me an error in certificates when KPL POST the message but i got the next error in logs:

***[AWS Log: ERROR](CurlHttpClient)Curl returned error code 60 - Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates***

```
Exception name: 
Error message: Unable to connect to endpoint
0 response headers:
2022-09-11 03:20:59.089  INFO 99719 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 03:20:59.089226] [0x00018612][0x00007f595bfff640] [info] [AWS Log: WARN](AWSClient)If the signature check failed. This could be because of a time skew. Attempting to adjust the signer.
2022-09-11 03:20:59.143  WARN 99719 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 03:20:59.143496] [0x00018612][0x00007f5981577640] [warning] [AWS Log: ERROR](CurlHttpClient)Curl returned error code 60 - Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
2022-09-11 03:20:59.143  WARN 99719 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 03:20:59.143556] [0x00018612][0x00007f5981577640] [warning] [AWS Log: ERROR](AWSClient)HTTP response code: -1
```

**I also tried to run it from another machine and here is the new logs:**

```
2022-09-11 17:12:29.293  INFO 2025772 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 17:12:29.293064] [0x001eea80][0x00007f23737fe700] [info] [AWS Log: WARN](AWSClient)If the signature check failed. This could be because of a time skew. Attempting to adjust the signer.
2022-09-11 17:12:29.470  INFO 2025772 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 17:12:29.470523] [0x001eea80][0x00007f2373fff700] [info] [AWS Log: WARN](AWSErrorMarshaller)Encountered AWSError 'UnrecognizedClientException': The security token included in the request is invalid.
2022-09-11 17:12:29.470  WARN 2025772 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-11 17:12:29.470572] [0x001eea80][0x00007f2373fff700] [warning] [AWS Log: ERROR](AWSClient)HTTP response code: 400
Exception name: UnrecognizedClientException
Error message: The security token included in the request is invalid.
6 response headers:
connection : close
content-length : 107
content-type : application/x-amz-json-1.1
date : Sun, 11 Sep 2022 15:12:29 GMT
x-amz-id-2 : HHnAW475wVldQOYvBAccWb5IobzQIQ4xpYTUC6fSVaSE0L5fCX/RAAimOR7Ii7Gm1/Q6Ssd2zUiAQaUM3wQPY1sGhXcJnr1D
x-amzn-requestid : ecd98905-dfba-07c0-b74e-7418d2d0b2eb
```

I feel it connects to AWS main amazon services not localstack services, because i see this line **Resolved remote host IP address: 3.91.171.213** in the next logs:

```
2022-09-12 01:13:53.335  WARN 2229288 --- [kpl-daemon-0003] c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    : [2022-09-12 01:13:53.335070] [0x0022058d][0x00007f90d3fff700] [warning] [AWS Log: ERROR](AWSClient)HTTP response code: 400
Resolved remote host IP address: 3.91.171.213
Request ID: ede9f5b6-bbb1-432e-b671-9847fa4df10d
Exception name: UnrecognizedClientException
Error message: The security token included in the request is invalid.
6 response headers:
connection : close
content-length : 107
content-type : application/x-amz-json-1.1
date : Sun, 11 Sep 2022 23:13:53 GMT
x-amz-id-2 : QozrFgS7zp3nKfs5X3wTkfj/dYBCTTEENBMTExhzOmXRGBBBa72Lu1ckuxz1JDrqWVgysVyb1v5+I4TBrIUbhf5B6+saa2k8
x-amzn-requestid : ede9f5b6-bbb1-432e-b671-9847fa4df10d
```

Here are my setup:

**1- localstack.yml** file which i am using to setup my stack on docker using the next command

> docker compose -f localstack.yml up

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=kinesis,dynamodb,cloudwatch
      - USE_SSL=false
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data # Local directory for saving persistent data
      - DEBUG=1
      - KINESIS_INITIALIZE_STREAMS=my-test-delivery-stream:2
    ports:
      - "4566-4584:4566-4584"
    volumes:
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  dynamodb-admin:
    image: aaronshaf/dynamodb-admin
    environment:
      - DYNAMO_ENDPOINT=localstack:4566
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
```

**2- application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  application:
    name: my-producer
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: timeSupplier
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          timeSupplier-out-0: output

      bindings:
        output:
          destination: my-test-delivery-stream
          content-type: text/plain

        timeSupplier-out-0:
          destination: my-test-delivery-stream
          content-type: text/plain

      kinesis:
        binder:
          checkpoint:
            table: my-test-delivery-stream-checkpoint
          locks:
            table: my-test-delivery-stream-locks
          kpl-kcl-enabled: true
          auto-create-stream: true
          auto-add-shards: true
          min-shard-count: 1
      poller:
        # trigger calling each 3 seconds
        fixed-delay: 3000
cloud:
  aws:
    kinesis:
      endpoint: http://localhost:4566
    dynamo-db:
      endpoint: http://localhost:4566
    cloud-watch:
      endpoint: http://localhost:4566
    credentials:
      accessKey: dummy
      secretKey: dummy
      profile-name: dummy
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    stack:
      auto: true

logging:
  level:
    root: TRACE
```

**3- AWS config** local component

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder;

@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class AwsConfigLocal {

  @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
  private String region;

  @Value("${cloud.aws.kinesis.endpoint}")

  private String kinesisEndpoint;

  @Value("${cloud.aws.dynamo-db.endpoint}")

  private String dynamoDbEndpoint;

  @Value("${cloud.aws.dynamo-db.endpoint}")

  private String cloudWatchEndpoint;

  @Bean
  public AmazonKinesisAsync amazonKinesisAsync() {
    return AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(kinesisEndpoint, region))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public AmazonDynamoDBAsync amazonDynamoDbAsync() {
    return AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDbEndpoint, region))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public AmazonCloudWatchAsync amazonCloudWatchAsync() {
    return AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(cloudWatchEndpoint, region))
        .build();
  }

}
```

**4- My producer** component which hold the creation of supplier bean

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestProducerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Supplier<String> timeSupplier() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(dtf);
    log.info("Sending message '{}' to kinesis", dateTime);
    return () -> dateTime;
  }
  
}
```

***Note***: I am using the next dependency version

> 

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring Cloud Stream.
This is just a matter of AWS KPL client and Localstack interactions.

According to [this GH issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/507), it looks like with the latest Localstack there is just enough to `setVerifyCertificate(false)` on the `KinesisProducerConfiguration`. Doesn't look like you have one at all. You can find one in my comment in that issue.